# Adding and removing data to/from iCal

Tags: python, applescript, icalendar

I need to add/remove calendar data to/from iCal.

I google and found that I can uses [python library](http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch15s04.xhtml) to create the ics file. With this, I can come up with applescript to run iCal to import the generated ics file to add calendar info to iCal, but for deleting calendar info, I don't know exactly what to do.

- Q1 : How to delete calendar data in iCal with applescript or python?
- Q2 : What would be other way to add calendar data in iCal?

Answer (score 1):

To delete the an event within iCal you need to be able to identify it. This can be done via the event's uid property or by some other identifying piece of information. Here's a quick example:

```
tell application "iCal"
    tell calendar "Chuck"
        set evt to make new event at end with properties ¬
            {description:"description", summary:"Summary", start date:get current date}
        set evtID to uid of evt
        set delEvt to every event whose summary is "Summary"
        delete delEvt
    end tell
end tell
```

You can find a list of the properties that are available for an event by taking a look at iCal's dictionary (File>Open Dictionary in Script Editor).